# minus reputation not shown in reputation tab

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I got reputation as `-1`. When I try to check that, I am not able to find where I got `-1`.

Please see below screenshot.

[image: minus reputation not shown]

Comment: What do you see if you check the "show deleted posts" at the bottom of the page?

Comment: It shows, 
+1 58 mins ago removed File transfer using Wi-FI Direct In Android ICS
-1 2 hours ago downvoted File transfer using Wi-FI Direct In Android ICS

But when I click on question, it is there. removed means what ?

Comment: The number in blue is indeed not updated when an answer you downvoted gets deleted, so the +1 did not affect it, leaving it at the -1 from the time you downvoted.

Comment: Answer is already there, not deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think it's a dupe. The issue is not the net reputation gain which is 0 but the number in blue background being -1. It's by design most likely and already reported, but can't find the dupe.

Comment: @Lafada: the answer on [File transfer using Wi-FI Direct In Android ICS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25562300) *is* deleted; it was deleted from review. You downvoted it 4 hours ago, it was deleted 3 hour ago.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: hrm, from the comments it appears to me that the question was answered by pointing out the checkbox and that the post was deleted..

Comment: @MartijnPieters this only explains why it's -1, but it doesn't mean the -1 should be there. IMO it's a valid bug report, which might end up as status-bydesign, but still.

Comment: Got it, When I donwvoted the answer i got `-1`. But after some time its deleted so I got `+1`. Due to this no change in my total. I was wondering why total no changed even got `-1`. Thanks all for your comments.